# MVC ActionLink does not return PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax to return information to a view via a PartialView.

The controller has two methods:

```
public ActionResult Deal()
{
    var product = getDeal();
    return PartialView("_deal",product);
}

private product getDeal()
{
    var product = db.Products.OrderByDescending(a => a.Name).First();
    product.Price *= 0.5m;
    return product;
}
```

The Index.cshtml for this controller has this section:

```
<div id="deal" class="container">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click here to see the daily deal!","Deal",
null,
new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "deal",
    InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod="GET"
},
new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

There is a PartialView _deal.cshtml in the Views folder but  ActionResult Deal() redirects to a /Products/Deal URL with just the data from _deal.cshtml on a page by itself. Instead of rendering a partial view and rendering the html in the div tag with id="deal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add nuget package of **Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax** to your project. From *Package Manager Console*:

`Search and install via NuGet Packages:  Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`

After that you need to add the references to your view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"> </script>
```

Your "Deal" ***ActionResult*** can be ***PartialViewResult*** and ***_deal.cshtml*** should be placed in the ***View > Shared*** *folder*.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and report back.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use it like**

**Store Your Value In Model and Pass Your Model.**

```
public ActionResult Deal()
        {
            return PartialView("../_ProductPartial",model)
        }
```